# preimages of closed sets are closed and Banach spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $T \colon X \to Y$ a continuous operator. Furthermore let $T^{-1}$ be continuous on $T(X)$. Why is $T(X)$ closed in $Y$?

I know preimages of closed sets are closed. But isn't the continuity of $T^{-1} \colon Y \to X$ sufficient to imply that $T(X)$ is closed in $Y$? Why and where do we need the assumption $T \colon X \to Y$ is continuous?

Comment: If your question is only about the neccesity of continuity of $T$, I also do not see why we need it.

Comment: $T^{-1}$ is only continuous on $T(X)$, not on $Y$. I think the closedness of $T(X)$ will follow from its completeness.

Comment: Yes, $X$ is closed, because $X$ is a Banach space. I also do not think that the continuity of $T$ is necessary.

Comment: It does not even make sense to write $T^{-1} : Y \to X$, unless $T$ is onto.

Answer (score 1):

Let me prove the following statement:

> Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces, $T:X\to Y$ linear and injective such that $T^{-1}:T(X)\to X$ is bounded. Then $T$ is continuous if and only if $T(X)$ is closed.

Proof: Assume $T$ continuous. Take a sequence $Tx_n \to y$ in $Y$. Then $(T^{-1}Tx_n)=(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $X$, hence convergent. By continuity $Tx_n \to Tx=y$, and $T(X)$ is closed.

Assume $T(X)$ is closed. Then $T(X)$ is complete. Hence $T^{-1}$ is a bijective, linear, continuous map between Banach spaces. By the open mapping theorem $T=(T^{-1})^{-1}$ is continuous.